# Approval lock/unlock with APEX

Tags: apex, approval-process, locking

I am in Winter '16 and trying to unlock and lock a record in APEX and I am getting the following exception

> FATAL_ERROR System.UnexpectedException: Apex approval lock/unlock api preference not enabled.

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to go to

`Setup -> Process Automation -> Process Automation Settings`

(if you use Classic interface -

`Setup->Create-> Workflows and Approvals -> Process Automation Settings`)

and set checkbox  **Enable record locking and unlocking in Apex**    as true

[image]
More information [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cg_task_admin_enable_apex_approval_lock.htm&type=5).