# Record Lock release

Tags: approval-process

I have created the record in order object in salesforce, once i changed the status as Submitted, the record gets locked in salesforce using Approval Process

I want to release the record in the object for field update using trigger and after updating the field, record to be locked. Can i get it through Rollback and commit? or Is this possible by using trigger?

The record is Locked  after the order gets submitted , after order gets submitted i want to Update the field in order in email Checkbox field , please verify the question - [Trigger in salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/152669/trigger-in-salesforce?noredirect=1#comment223848_152669)

I am getting Error in salesforce while adding the attachment to the order , because order record gets submitted and locked,I want unlock the Record and update the field and again lock the record using trigger coding in attachment trigger

Error Message:

> Error: Apex trigger AutoAttachmentSend caused an unexpected exception,
>   contact your administrator: AutoAttachmentSend: execution of
>   AfterInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First
>   exception on row 0 with id 8018E000000jvurQAA; first error:
>   INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY, user does not have access to use
>   approval assignment email template: []: Trigger.AutoAttachmentSend:
>   line 29, column 1 How to rectify the error,In order to prevent the Recursive Emails

In attachment trigger:

```
for(Order or1: Orderlst)
    {
       if(!or1.Email_Sent__c){
        or1.Email_Sent__c = true; //update here
        Orderdetail.put(or1.id,or1);
        Accountid.add (or1.accountid);
      }
    }
update Orderlst;
```

> while updating the email checkbox field after order gets submitted , I
>   want to unlock the order object record and update the checkbox field
>   and again locked , If anyone knows please provide me code for my Operation

Comment: @Tushar sharma can you suggest ?

Comment: ?? apex runs in system context and when field update occurs, a) the record is updated and b) the trigger executes. Are you getting a specific error preventing the trigger from executing? A short code fragment would be useful here. Please use [edit] to amend your post

Comment: @cropredy once the order gets submitted, record is locked and attachement added for the partcular order, inorder to prevent recursive email, i have created email sent check box in order, while updating the order i am getting the error-

Comment: Please use [edit] to amend your question with additional detail.  Don't use comments

Comment: @cropredy see my Updated Question can you guide me the code for my question?

Comment: @cropredy Now your Ok, please guide

Comment: shall i use apporaval.unlock(or1,true) and approval.lock(ordrlst,false) @cropredy

Comment: @cropredy guide me what i have to do , I will proceed my next step

Comment: @cropredy if i use the line in the code: it is showing Error: 
Error: Apex trigger AutoAttachmentSend caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: AutoAttachmentSend: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.UnexpectedException: Apex approval lock/unlock api preference not enabled.: Trigger.AutoAttachmentSend: line 31, column 1

Comment: @Tushar sharma are you there?

Comment: specific error message in comment is addressed here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/108524/approval-lock-unlock-with-apex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Apex [Approval](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_approval.htm) class has a variety of methods to check if a record is `isLocked`, to `unlock` a record and to `lock` a record. So you should be able to write a trigger that uses these methods to accomplish the field update.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/152669/trigger-in-salesforce?noredirect=1#comment223848_152669 @keith can you please suggest for this question I am facing, could you please some snippet of code for update the order object for updating checkbox field after the order gets submitted

Comment: @user36188 I don't understand your comment. In my answer I'm saying yes you can unlock and re-lock in a trigger.

Comment: yes@Keithc , I have unlock and lock in the trigger for order object for updating the checkbox field after order gets submitted

Comment: Can you please answer my question @Keith C